# How to use vfork from within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script

If we want to `fork` anything from inside a bash script (or even at the command line), we can simply surround it with $() or back-ticks. For example;

`echo $(ls)` - this will fork the current environment and run ls within the (forked) subshell

How can we use `vfork` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) instead of the standard fork functionality?

Comment: Do you want the functionality of the parent blocking, or do you actually want to use the `vfork` function itself.  If you're really concerned about performance benefits you should probably not be using any sort of shell as your development language

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `grep -Ri vfork` in the bash source code doesn't find any hits, so there's no way to directly use vfork from bash.

If you just want something that will invoke a child and block the parent, well, your subshell example already does that.  Otherwise `echo` would likely get at best incomplete results.

You can also run a command in the background with `&` and then use `wait` to have the parent block until the child finishes.

Comment: Yes all good thoughts/comments. We have a script which does A LOT of forking and we want to make it faster. Hence the looking into vfork. Surely there must be a way to somehow call vfork instead of fork, even if we have to write a little C wrapper or something. It would be good though to be able to easily change the actual `fork` call into something else - in pseudo code for example; `vork=true; echo $(ls)`

Comment: If performance is an issue, shell scripting is probably not the right solution.  If there's just one performance critical part you might write that in something fast like C and then you can call that from bash, but bash is not really built for speed